# CSV Data Config Not Sending Data to HTTP Request

Tags: java, csv, jmeter

I have recorded a test script for user authentication and am trying to send data by using a CSV file. I have tried this previously for a post request and the parameters were being sent fine but it doesnt seem to be working for the test script.

The error i get in my response body from the result tree is:
**{"EXCEPTION":"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException","ERROR":"com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 16 path $.username"}**

Attaching screenshots below for you to understand better.

[Variables I've set for authenticate call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XpTd.png)

[Settings for my CSV Data Set Config element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2soDK.png)

Comment: how your CSV looks like? does it have a header row?

Comment: @user7294900 you mean names of the columns by header row? if yes, then no, i didnt add them. I directly added username and password in the format -> username, pass

Comment: @user7294900 the format is in a single column and it worked fine on a basic post call i sent.

Comment: do you use infinite loop in thread group? then move CSV Data Set Config as child of thread group

Comment: @user7294900 No, i only increase the number of threads acc to the no. of users i want. And yes ive tried with CSV Data Set Config as a child of thread group as well as the HTTP request for authenticate and both give me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help without seeing:

1. First 2 lines of your CSV file
2. Whether the variables are getting read by JMeter (output of the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/))
3. What request is actually being sent to the server (Request -> Request Body) tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
4. Any suspicious entries from [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

if you won't be able to figure out what's wrong using the above hints - update your question with all the mentioned data and we'll try to assist

Comment: You were right! My CSV file wasnt configured properly, hence the wrong string was being passed. Thank you (: